# Inserting 3d chart from Google Sheet into email as an image using Appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, charts, google-sheets, google-visualization

I am trying to insert 3D charts from google sheet into email using the below code but the image in the email is getting converted to 2D.
Can anyone help me to pull the charts from google sheet into an email with all its properties intact?

The Original Chart[image]

The Chart in Email[image]

```
function email(sheet, toMail, ccMail, msg){
  var charts = sheet.getCharts();
  var emailImages={};
  var chartBlobs=new Array(charts.length); 
  for(var i=0;i<charts.length;i++){    
    chartBlobs[i]= charts[i].getAs("image/png").setName("chartBlob"+i);
    emailBody= emailBody + "<p align='left'><img src='cid:chart"+i+"'></p>";
    emailImages["chart"+i]= chartBlobs[i];
  }
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: toMail,    
    cc: ccMail,
    subject: "ABC",   
    htmlBody: emailBody,
    inlineImages:emailImages});

}
```

Comment: Have you tried 'image/bmp', 'image/gif',  or 'image/jpeg'?

Comment: thanks for responding @TheMaster.I had tried 'image/bmp', 'image/gif', and 'image/jpeg' but all gave me 2D Charts

Comment: @TheMaster I think that this might be a bug. Because I confirmed 2 same situations except for my environment. So I would like to report this situation to the issue tracker. So I proposed a current workaround.

Comment: @Tanaike Good. If you do open a issue, Link it here, so that people might star it.

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for replying. I reported this situation to [the issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131557147). I hope this issue is modified in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to send email including the 3D chart on Spreadsheet.

If my understanding is correct, how about this workaround? I experienced the same issue with you. When the chart on Spreadsheet are retrieved as a blob, the chart of the blob is different from the original chart. I think that this might be a bug. In this case, as one of several workarounds, I used the following flow.

#### Flow of modified script:

1. Retrieve charts from Spreadsheet.
2. Create Google Slides as a temporal.
3. Insert the charts to Slides as images.
4. Retrieve the inserted charts as blobs.
5. Send email including the retrieved blob.
6. Remove the temporal Google Slides.

#### Modified script:

In this modification, I modified your script. Please modify your script as follows.

```
function email(sheet, toMail, ccMail, msg){
  var charts = sheet.getCharts();

  var slides = SlidesApp.create("sample"); // Added
  var slide = slides.getSlides()[0]; // Added

  var emailImages={};
  var chartBlobs=new Array(charts.length);
  var emailBody = ""; // Added
  for(var i=0;i<charts.length;i++){
    var image = slide.insertSheetsChartAsImage(charts[i]); // Added
    chartBlobs[i]= image.getAs("image/png").setName("chartBlob"+i); // Modified
    emailBody= emailBody + "<p align='left'><img src='cid:chart"+i+"'></p>";
    emailImages["chart"+i]= chartBlobs[i];
  }
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: toMail,
    cc: ccMail,
    subject: "ABC",
    htmlBody: emailBody,
    inlineImages:emailImages});

  DriveApp.getFileById(slides.getId()).setTrashed(true); // Added
}
```

#### Note:

- In this modified script, the temporal Google Slides is moved to the trash box.
- I reported this issue to [the issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131557147).

#### References:

- [Save a canvas image to google drive.](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-apps-script-community/5hTLn9xd-gQ/ToGnCk43CwAJ)

  - Also I proposed above workaround here.
- [insertSheetsChartAsImage()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#insertsheetschartasimagesourcechart)
- [setTrashed()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#settrashedtrashed)

If I misunderstood your question and this workaround was not what you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tanaike.Your work around worked so perfectly.Now I am getting the same chart as in the Google Sheet.Hats off to you.

Comment: @Sree Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. And I reported this situation to [the issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131557147). I hope this issue is modified in the future.